# undefined method `permit' for nil:NilClass with a locale selector, how to prevent it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have multi-language application that uses a dropdown to switch between languages (locales). When you choose an element from the dropdown it submits a form that goes to a certain controller with a parameter 'set_locale=es'.
It always fails with a message: "**`` undefined method `permit' for nil:NilClass ``**".

This is quite obvious:

- the form is made with `form_tag mymodel_path`, where MyModel is an
  existing ActiveRecord model, with its complete CRUD scaffold.
- The "routes.rb" file says `resources :mymodel`, this means that the route
  `POST   (/:locale)/mymodels(.:format) mymodels#create` does exist.
- The form works with POST model, so when I use the locale selector the
  controller receives a POST and thinks I'm creating a new MyModel, so
  it routes to `#create` method that calls the line
  `params[:mymodel].permit(:title,:and_more)` that obviously raises the exception.

How can I solve this?
Is there a way to route a POST request with parameter "set_locale" to #index instead of #create ?

Note: I'm following the chapter "15. Internationalization" of the book "Agile web development with Rails" 4th ed., by Pragmatic Programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's try to sort this out a bit.

**First** about the final question: yes, you can route anything to anywhere using your routes.rb file. Just put something like

```
post '/:locale/mymodels' => 'mymodels#index', :as => "set_locale"
```

and then usee the `set_locale_path` in your `form_tag`. You'll need to handle the locale setting in the index method in the controller.

**Second** Personaly I prefer not to double the routes and just send the locale using GET (`/some/path?locale=en`). This way you don't need to add any routes, you just change your form method to get and the path to `mymodels_path` (the index action route). You can even replace the form with links then using `mymodels_path(:locale => 'en')`.

**Third** When you try to handle mass_asignment protection, you should address the params directly. So it will be something like

```
def mymodel_params
  params.require(:mymodel).permit(:title, :and_more)
end
```

This way you don't need to care about what params are sent to your controller, it will not break if you miss something.